# Clicking on row and on links in the row

Tags: jquery, html

Unfortunately I wasn't able to come up with a better title. Here's my problem. I have a table (HTML). I would like a solution where if I click anywhere on the rows, it shows me details about that row in overlay. This part is ok, I can do that with jQuery TOOLS. But I also have links in certain columns, and when I click on them, I don't want this overlay to pop up. I'm sorry if this question was already answered, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to show the code you are currently using so people can give advice on how to deactivate the tooltip for specific columns.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by generating the nth-column you wan't to have different behaviour with a designated class:

Let's say this is your row:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td class="dont-process-click">3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

...

And have you're click event run only if the clicked td doesn't have that class.

```
            $("td").click( function() {
                if(! $(this).hasClass('dont-process-click')) {
                    alert('Do something');
                }
            });
```

Comment: This can be even further optimised by selecting only those `TD`s that are relevant thus making `if` statement unnecessary? `$("td:not(.dont-process-click)")`

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1: Prevent event bubbling on links

Choose a selector that fits your needs for those links:

```
$("table tr td a").click(function(evt){
    // will prevent bubbling of click event
    evt.stopPropagation();
})
```

As you can see this works **at the source** of event (link itself). This will stop click event propagation to your table row hence detail overlay/popup won't execute. **But** this will only work if you're not using `live/delegate` event registration.

### Solution 2: Checking event target

This solution check in your table row's click event whether target is not a link. Keep your table row selector as is (this one here's just for the proof of concept):

```
$("table tr").click(function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "a")
    {
        // functionality you're running now
    }
});
```

This will make sure that you will be showing that popup only when anything else has been clicked than an anchor `A` element. This solution works **at the destination** compared to solution 1.

### Special notes

If you're using `live` (or `delegate`) event registration for your links, solution 1 won't work at all. Solution 2 is the one to go with in that particular case. `live/delegate` actually registers event with some upper ancestor element in the DOM tree (`live` with document itself) that checks selector match on the execution. If you'd cancel event bubbling, `live` events wouldn't trigger at all because thy require event propagation/bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on link columns and select other columns in jquery selector to show pop up.
Hope It helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  $('.row').click(function(event){

    if($(event.target).is('a.special')){  // if it's special, than don't pop-open modal

      return false;

    }

    // Open modal.

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write two click function in jquery for table td and table td a elements.for examples :
$(document).ready(function(){
  //for tr click
   $('table tr').click(function(){
    // generate overlay
    });

//for anchor
   $('table tr td a').click(function(){
   //do something
  });
});